# Number with apostrophe in direction rtl

Tags: html, css, localization, right-to-left

I'm currently working on localization of our site for right-to-left layout. We have numbers where every three digits are separated by single quote mark, e.g. -1'190.55. In rtl this number should be 1'190.55-. But when put 'direction: rtl' to the styles, the number becomes 190.55'1-.
The numbers are put dynamically and could not be cut manually.

HTML:

`<div>-1'190.55</div>`

CSS:

`div {
  direction: rtl
}`

Comment: I don't think you can do that without additional markup. I could produce 190.55'1-, 55.091'1- and -1'190.55, but not 1'190.55-. https://jsfiddle.net/w4Lj402n/ So the answer is probably to put the number excluding the minus sign in a span, perhaps using JavaScript.

Comment: Probably, you're right. I also think about this solution.

Comment: OK, I posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible, by putting a span in the div. So if you can change the HTML at all, that's the recommended way to do it.
Note: put the minus sign outside the span.

```css
div {
  direction: rtl
}

div span {
   unicode-bidi:embed; direction:ltr;
}
```

```html
<div>-<span>1'190.55</span></div>
```

If you can't change the HTML, but you can use JavaScript, then it's possible too, albeit in a more convoluted way.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i<divs.length; ++i) {
  var content = divs[i].innerHTML, min = content.indexOf('-')==0 ?1 :0;
  divs[i].innerHTML = content.substring(0,min)+'<span>'+content.substring(min)+'</span>';
}
```

```css
div {
  direction: rtl
}

div span {
   unicode-bidi:embed; direction:ltr;
}
```

```html
<div>-1'190.55</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your markup is flexible, try adding a `<span>` inside the `<div>` with `direction:ltr`

```css
div {
  direction: rtl
}
span{
display: block;
direction: ltr;
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div><span>-1'190.55<span></div>
```

Comment: The result is -1'190.55 but should be 1'190.55-

Comment: then please move '-' outside of span.

Comment: The numbers are put dynamically and could not be cut manually.